# Storing GET from my Node API to my Angular service

Tags: node.js, angular, api

I'm sorry if this has already been asked, I've been through tons of posts and docs, but nothing quite sounds like what I'm trying to do, even if I think that it's rather simple.

I'm building a tiny web app. It has 2 directories : api (node, working on **:8080**) and app (angular, working on **:4200**). They work pretty well separately, my database is ready, everything is fine. Thanks to Json Proxy (I don't use CORS), my API routes are working in my Angular app, for instance :

localhost:4200/api/users URL will GET all my users, no problem. I thought I've done the hardest part, but now I'm stuck on one simple thing : How the hell do I use these API routes in TypeScript for my Angular Service. Like, from this service, **I want to manipulate the datas already accessible** from localhost:4200/api/users. Nothing more. How to use/call this URL/route in code ?

I'm confused by the lack of doc on this matter, sounds like such a basic thing to me. If anyone can point me to the right direction, I'd be glad. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Did you check the Angular HTTP documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Angular and nodejs routes are different. localhost:4200/api/users

//services.service.ts

```
callapifunction(name: string, pass: string, confirmPass: string): Observable<any> {
  const body = new HttpParams()
      .set('username', name)
      .set('password', pass)

  return this.http.post(
      `localhsot:8080/api/users`,
      body
  )
      .pipe(
          tap(_ => console.log(_)),
          catchError(this.handleError<any>('verify'))
      );
}
```

You can call it any component. Thats it. Angular routers declared in router.

//app-routing.module.ts

```
import {Route} from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
export const routerConfig: Route[] = [
    {
        path: '',
        children:[
            //admin
            {
                path: 'api/users',
                component: DashboardComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'main/login',
                component: LoginComponent
            },

        ]},

    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: '/'
    }
];
```